# How to check for uncommitted changes in the working area using go-git

Tags: git, go, go-git

I'm currently working on a web editor integrated with Git using the go-git library. I'm looking for a way to programmatically check for modifications in the working area before adding files to a commit.

I've gone through the go-git documentation, and the closest thing I found is the [Patch API](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4@v4.13.1/plumbing/object#Commit.Patch). However, it seems to be geared towards showing the changes between two commits rather than changes in the working area that haven't been committed yet.

I'm curious to know if go-git supports the behavior of identifying and viewing modifications in the working area before they are added to a commit. If it does, could someone provide guidance or a clue on how to achieve this using the library?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go-git allows you to check the status of the repo. This file holds that code: https://github.com/go-git/go-git/blob/master/status.go

The main doc page does not show this piece. But if we extend the example there, it's something like this:

```
r, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), nil, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL: "https://github.com/go-git/go-billy",
})
CheckIfError(err)

wt, err := r.Worktree()
CheckIfError(err)

st, _ := wt.Status()
if st.IsClean() {
    fmt.Println("no changes to commit")
    return
}
```

You can also check a file path for untracked status, with the `IsUntracked()` method.

Note `CheckIfError` is not a method in the package. Just placeholder for some error check to implement on your side.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I really appreciate it!

While the information you provided about checking the repository status is helpful, I'm looking for a way to retrieve the actual diff changes in the working area, similar to what the `git diff` command would display. This is crucial for GUI users, as it allows them to view the specific modifications made to a file before deciding whether to commit it.

Comment: I missed that detail, apologies. I'm not sure it's integrated with the library, based on this convo: https://github.com/go-git/go-git/issues/881